# React Bootstrap Table is not displaying the data fetched from api response

Tags: reactjs

I am building an app for fetching weather details in React JS.I have written an api call which returns few data relevant to weather and I am trying to populate that in React Bootstrap Table.But ia m getting the below error-

```
TypeError: nextProps.data.slice is not a function

    at BootstrapTable.componentWillReceiveProps (BootstrapTable.js:560)

    at callComponentWillReceiveProps (react-dom.development.js:11527)

    at updateClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:11719)

    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13153)

    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:13824)

    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:15863)

    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:15902)
```

My code-

```
import React from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import moment from "moment";
import axios from "axios";
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from "react-bootstrap-table";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

class Landing extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      cityName: "",
      startDate: moment(),
      weatherDetails: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

  handleCityChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      cityName: event.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    console.log("button clicked");
    e.preventDefault();
    let requestData = {
      cityName: this.state.cityName,
      date: moment(this.state.startDate).format()
    };

    const cityVal = this.state.cityName;
    const dateVal = moment(this.state.startDate).format();

    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: `http://localhost:8765/weatherUI/weather/citydate/${cityVal}/${dateVal}`,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      data: requestData
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({
          weatherDetails: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-3">City Name</div>
              <div className="col-sm-6">
                <select
                  data-style="btn-new"
                  value={this.state.cityName}
                  onChange={this.handleCityChange}
                >
                  <option value="">Select any city..</option>
                  <option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
                  <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
                  <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
                  <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
                  <option value="Pune">Pune</option>
                  <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
                  <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-3">
                <div className="col-sm-6">Date</div>

                <DatePicker
                  selected={this.state.startDate}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-12">
                <button className="btn-primary">
                  {" "}
                  Click to get Weather details
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <BootstrapTable data={this.state.weatherDetails}>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="cityName" isKey>
                City name
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="countryName">
                Country Name
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="temperature">
                Temperature
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="cloudsDescription">
                Clouds Description
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="windDescription">
                Wind Description
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="pressure">
                Pressure
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="humidityPercentage">
                Humidity Percentage
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="date">Date</TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Landing;
```

response.data -

```
{
   "cityName": "kolkatta",

    "countryName": "india",

     "weatherDescription": "light rain",

     "temperature": "25",

     "cloudsDescription": "Broken Clouds",

     "windDescription": "Moderate breeze, 7.2 m/s, West-northwest (290)",

      "pressure": "1007 ",

       "humidityPercentage": "79",

       "date": "2018-08-03"
     }
```

I am using React bootstrap table version 4.3.1. I have used his before and have worked fine. Not sure what is creating this issue. Can someone let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks!!

Comment: it looks like the error is not coming from this component

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps ` is not used in this component.

Comment: Error means at that time `data` prop is not an array. You are setting `weatherDetails` as an empty array in your state, so actually it should work. So, maybe `response.data` would be anything beside an array? Can you see an array in your `console.log`?

Comment: My response is coming in form of object as a response. I have tried setting weatherDetails as an empty object inside my state but I am getting error again.

Comment: My response.data is an object.

Comment: This is why you are getting the error. If there is an array in the response.data, just pick it up then set your state with that.

Comment: Can you suggest me a way to work with object format?

Comment: What does the response look like? If `BootstrapTable` waits for an array then you can't use an object here. Please share your `response.data`. You can update your question.

Comment: I have update my question with response.data.

Comment: So, you query for a specific city and got this response. If `BootStrap` component needs an array you can set your state simply like that maybe: `weatherDetails: [ response.data ]`

Comment: I am able to achieve this by changing the data type as array in backend. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't it work just changing the setState like I suggested? Most of the time we don't have the ability to change the response we get.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the response.data format to array in backend solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

React boostrap table expects array and you are passing an object. So if you want to solve this in frontend, below changes in handleSubmit should fix the issue. Basically i created an array and when i get resposne from backend as an object, i push it to array.

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    console.log("button clicked");
    const weatherDetails = [];
    e.preventDefault();
    let requestData = {
      cityName: this.state.cityName,
      date: moment(this.state.startDate).format()
    };

    const cityVal = this.state.cityName;
    const dateVal = moment(this.state.startDate).format();

    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: `http://localhost:8765/weatherUI/weather/citydate/${cityVal}/${dateVal}`,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      data: requestData
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        weatherDetails.push(data);
        this.setState({
          weatherDetails,
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```